# Files reading differently in linux? C++

Tags: c++, linux, mingw32

I'm a fairly new programmer, but I consider my google-fu quite competent and I've spent several hours searching.

I've got a simple SDL application that reads from a binary file (2 bytes as a magic number, then 5 bytes per "tile")
it then displays each tile in the buffer, the bytes decide the x,y,id,passability and such.
So it's just level loading really.

It runs fine on any windows computer (tested windows server 2008, 7/64 and 7/32)
but when I compile it on linux, it displays random tiles in random positions.
I'd be tempted to say it's reading from the wrong portion in the RAM, but I implimented the magic number so it'd return an error if the first 2 bytes were out.

I'd love to figure this out myself but it's bugging me to hell now and I can't progress much further with it unless I can program on the move (my laptop runs linux).
I'm using G++ on linux, mingw32g++ on windows.

```
bool loadlevel(int level_number)
{
    int length;
    std::string filename;
    filename = "Levels/level";
    filename += level_number+48;
    filename += ".lvl";
    std::ifstream level;
    level.open(filename.c_str(),std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    level.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
    length = level.tellg();
    level.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
    char buffer[length];
    level.read(buffer,length);
    if (buffer[0] == 0x49 && buffer[1] == 0x14)
    {
        char tile_buffer[BYTES_PER_TILE];
        int buffer_place = 1;
        while(buffer_place < length)
        {
            for (int i = 1;i <= BYTES_PER_TILE;i++)
            {
                tile_buffer[i] = buffer[buffer_place+1];
                buffer_place++;
            }
            apply_surface(tile_buffer[1],tile_buffer[2],tiles,screen,&clip[tile_buffer[3]]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // File is invalid
        return false;
    }
    level.close();
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code.

It seems likely that you've made some assumptions about how the compiler will do things; different platforms have (slightly) different conventions about things like structure packing. Post the code and someone will quickly figure it out.

Comment: You might want to include which compilers you're using on each platform.

Comment: i've updated the code with more relevant information

Comment: Are you usingt the same binary file on both windows and linux? In that case how have you created this binary file?

Comment: Yes it's the same file (I use dropbox so it's perfectly synchronised)
I have viewed the file in a hex editor, it is the same on both. (it's a seperate program to create the binary file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array handling is incorrect.
Array indexing in C/C++ begins from 0.

You have defined 'tile_buffer' to be an array sized 'BYTES_PER_TILE'.
If BYTES_PER_TILE was 5, your array would have elements tile_buffer[0] to tile_buffer[4].

In your inner for-loop you loop from 1 to 5 so a buffer overflow will occur.

I don't know if this is the cause of your problem but it certainly won't help matters.

Comment: Thankyou, fixing the code solved the problem! Makes me wonder why it worked properly on windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not an answer, but the 1-based array handling and the unneeded copying make my head hurt.

Why not just do something along these lines?

```
if ((length >= 2+BYTES_PER_TILE) && (buf[0] == CONST1) && (buf[1] == CONST2)) {
    for (char *tile = &buf[2]; tile < &buf[length-BYTES_PER_TILE]; tile+=BYTES_PER_TILE) {
        apply_surface(tile[0],tile[1],tiles,screen,&clip[tile[2]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a new programmer, but i'll have a look at that code and see if I can use it to optimize my program a little, thankyou!